# image save in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image and after drawing some features(ellipses and text) on it I want to save it as JPEG.

```
h= figure(1);
imagesc(im_name);
colormap('gray');
hold on
for i=1:no_of_points;
//draw features and write some text
end
hold off
imsave (h);
```

I am getting a figure with features drawn on it but when I save it, it is an image (which is my orignal image 'im_name') without new features on it.

I tried also

```
.
.
.

imsave (h);
hold off
```

Thanx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try the function `saveas`

> ## saveas
>
> Save figure or Simulink block diagram using specified format
>
> ## Alternatives
>
> Use File > Save As on the figure window menu to access the Save As
>   dialog, in which you can select a graphics format. For details, see
>   Exporting in a Specific Graphics Format in the MATLAB Graphics
>   documentation. Sizes of files written to image formats by this GUI and
>   by saveas can differ due to disparate resolution settings.  Syntax
>
> saveas(h,'filename.ext')  saveas(h,'filename','format')
>
> ## Description
>
> saveas(h,'filename.ext') saves the figure or Simulink block diagram
>   with the handle h to the file filename.ext. The format of the file is
>   determined by the extension, ext. Allowable values for ext are listed
>   in this table.
>
> You can pass the handle of any Handle Graphics object to saveas, which
>   then saves the parent figure to the object you specified should h not
>   be a figure handle. This means that saveas cannot save a subplot
>   without also saving all subplots in its parent figure.

Answer (score 0):

When using the saveas function the resolution isn't as good as when manually saving the figure with File-->Save As..., It's more recommended to use hgexport instead, as follows:

```
hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
```

This will do exactly as manually saving the figure.

[Source](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PT49C/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1PT49C).